# Script tool Error - ERROR 000735: Y Field (Latitude): Value is required Failed to execute (ConvertCoordinateNotation)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, error-000735

I've a python code which was working in ArcGIS 10, but now since I've migrated to 10.2.2 didn't work.Basically it's a toolset which runs a python script. The tool allow the user to input coordinates in DMS or DDM, create the points and after track the path.Here is my error message:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\GP_TOOLS\VesselTrack.py", line 54, in <module>
        arcpy.ConvertCoordinateNotation_management(TableTemp, output_Vessel, "LATLONG","", coordinateformat, "DD")
      File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 7652, in ConvertCoordinateNotation
        raise e
    ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
    ERROR 000735: Y Field (Latitude): Value is required
    Failed to execute (ConvertCoordinateNotation).


Failed to execute (VesselTrack).
```

The following is the code:

```
#import arcgisscripting
import arcpy, os
from math import radians, sin, cos
from arcpy import env


# get the input & output parameters
latitude = str(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0))
longitude = str(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1))
coordinateformat = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
description = str(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3))
link1 = str(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4))
link2 = str(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5))
delhistory = str(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6))
output_Vessel = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(7)
output_Track = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(8)

# Create table
TablePath, outFC = os.path.split(output_Vessel)
TableName = "TableTemp"
TableTemp = os.path.join(TablePath, TableName)
arcpy.CreateTable_management(TablePath, TableName)

if str(coordinateformat) == "DDM" :
    arcpy.AddField_management(TableTemp, "LAT", "TEXT", "", "", 50)
    arcpy.AddField_management(TableTemp, "LON", "TEXT", "", "", 50)

    rows = arcpy.InsertCursor(TableTemp)
    row = rows.newRow()
    row.setValue("LAT", latitude)
    row.setValue("LON", longitude)
    rows.insertRow(row)

    del row
    del rows

    # Convert coordinates and create FC
    arcpy.ConvertCoordinateNotation_management(Table, output_Vessel, "LON", "LAT", coordinateformat, "DD")


if str(coordinateformat) == "DMS" :
    arcpy.AddField_management(TableTemp, "LATLONG", "TEXT", "", "", 50)

    rows = arcpy.InsertCursor(TableTemp)
    row = rows.newRow()
    row.setValue("LATLONG", latitude + " " + longitude)
    rows.insertRow(row)

    del row
    del rows

    # Convert Coordinate Notation
    arcpy.ConvertCoordinateNotation_management(TableTemp, output_Vessel, "LATLONG","", coordinateformat, "DD")

# Add the attributes to the Point FC
arcpy.AddField_management(output_Vessel, "DESCR", "TEXT", "", "", 5000)
arcpy.AddField_management(output_Vessel, "LINK1", "TEXT", "", "", 255)
arcpy.AddField_management(output_Vessel, "LINK2", "TEXT", "", "", 255)

arcpy.CalculateField_management(output_Vessel, "DESCR", '"' + description + '"', "PYTHON_9.3")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(output_Vessel, "LINK1", '"' + link1 + '"', "PYTHON_9.3")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(output_Vessel, "LINK2", '"' + link2 + '"', "PYTHON_9.3")

# Keep the history (or remove if indicated)
vessel_history = "//servername/data/Geoprocessing/TEST/GP_TOOLS_Vessel_Tracking/GP_Output.gdb/Output"

if delhistory == 'true':
    arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management(vessel_history)

arcpy.Append_management(output_Vessel, vessel_history, "NO_TEST")
arcpy.Delete_management(output_Vessel)
arcpy.Copy_management(vessel_history, output_Vessel)

# Create line track
Empty_Track = "//servername/data/Geoprocessing/TEST/GP_TOOLS_Vessel_Tracking/GP_Output.gdb/Empty_Track"
if delhistory == 'true':
    arcpy.Copy_management(Empty_Track, output_Track)

arcpy.PointsToLine_management(output_Vessel, output_Track)

# Delete temp files
arcpy.Delete_management(Table)
```

This line is blocking the process:  `arcpy.ConvertCoordinateNotation_management(TableTemp, output_Vessel, "LATLONG","", coordinateformat, "DD")`

Can anyone highlight me if I missing something... Seems like he is no getting one of the parameters to create the feature class with the points. I want it to works on ArcGIS Desktop, so I can publish it and create a geoprocessing widget in flex viewer later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"DMS" is not one of the supported coordinate formats, use "DMS_1" instead. See the [help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/convert-coordinate-notation.htm) for the list of formats.

> DMS_1 —Both longitude and latitude values are in a single field. Two values are separated by a space, a comma, or a slash.
>
> For DD_1, DDM_1, and DMS_1, the latitude and longitude values required to represent a location are concatenated into a single string and stored in a single field.

Comment: Hi, yes you are right. I just found out that this parameter has changed from version 10 to 10.2.2. So I did the following adjustments: DMS to DMS_1 / DDM to DDM_2 and DD to DD_2. By the way now I got a different error message: Error 999999

Comment: @Dkitoko if my answer works for you then please click the tick to mark it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Luke, I managed to make it work putting the correct formats and changing the way that I was creating the DMS field.